# Is it possible to construct proof systems that look consistent for short proofs, but are actually inconsistent?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

What's the shortest axiom you can add to a system like ZFC to make it inconsistent such that the shortest proof of a contradiction has length n? Is the length of the axiom lower-bounded by Ω(n), or is it possible to do better?

Are there any known examples of systems which are inconsistent, but the length of the shortest proof of a contradiction is exponential in the length of the axioms?

Is there a standard terminology for systems that "look consistent" when only considering short proofs, but fail to be consistent for longer proofs?

Comment: My guess is that it's possible to do better than Ω(n).

Let H(x) be a cryptographic hash function, and let IterH(k, x) = H(H(...k times...H(x)...)). For n ∈ ℕ, the statement "IterH(2^n, 0) = 0" (which is almost certainly false) has length O(log(n)). If we add "IterH(2^n, 0) = 0" as an axiom to ZFC, it almost certainly makes the system inconsistent, but ZFC shouldn't be able to access the actual output of IterH(2^n, 0) to prove the contradiction without simulating an exponential-length computation in the proof.

Maybe a time hierarchy theorem can let us remove the cryptographic assumption?

Comment: Classic example is the sentence that says "this statement has no ZFC proof with length < (big number)". The sentence is provable in ZFC (so ZFC+ its negation proves a contradiction) but its proof is longer than (big number). How it scales is only limited by how much you can compress (big number). (And there's nothing particular to ZFC here... can do the same thing in PA, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! How do we know that its proof is longer than (big number)? I can see that if the proof needs to enumerate all proofs smaller than (big number), or even just reference a single proof of size approximately (big number), this works, but what rules out there being some clever method of proving statements of that form in a much shorter way, like by induction on (big number) or something like that?

Comment: Because you can prove a contradiction from the negation of that statement just as fast as you can prove that statement (plus or minus a step). This is because $T+\neg\varphi\vdash \bot$ if and only if $T\vdash \varphi$.

Comment: @TaylorHornby There's a more thorough analysis, but just as a quick justification, if there were a shorter proof than that, ZFC would prove an incorrect statement, which would be big news.

Comment: @TaylorHornby Actually not difficult at all to reduce the correctness assumption to consistency here: if the statement were ZFC-provable in fewer than (big number) steps, then ZFC would prove that fact, and thus prove the statement's negation.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, thank you for answering!

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You should post that as an answer. (Incidentally, you and the OP may also be interested in [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417484/proving-short-consistency-can-we-do-better-than-brute-force-search).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Reproducing my comment as an answer on suggestion.*

---

The classic example, [due to the man himself,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem) is a sentence $G_n$ which says (via the standard diagonalization trick)

> I am not provable from $T$ in fewer than n symbols

where $T$ is some consistent, c.e., $\Sigma_1$-complete theory.

If $G_n$ were provable in $T$ by fewer than $n$ symbols, $T$ would be able to prove this, and hence refute $G_n$ and be inconsistent, so the sentence is true. But then, just by checking all proofs of length less than $n,$ $T$ will be able to prove $G_n$. So $G_n$ is provable, but the proof requires more than $n$ symbols. Thus, $T + \{\lnot G_n\}$ is an inconsistent system with no proof of inconsistency shorter than $n.$

How slowly the size of the shortest possible implementation of $G_n$ scales with $n$ is only limited by how much $T$ is capable of compressing $n$. Note that this is the only point at which the strength of $T$ (beyond $\Sigma_1$-completeness) becomes relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Take the formula $p \to \neg \neg p$ in a Hilbert-style axiom system with only inference rule Modus Ponens and axioms

- $\varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi)$ (I1)
- $(\varphi\to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$  (I2)
- $\neg \varphi \to (\varphi \to \psi)$ (I3)
- $(\varphi \to \neg \varphi) \to \neg \varphi$ (I4)

Next, add in the ZF axioms and define

- $\xi:=(\neg \neg p \to p)$
- $\phi_0:=((\xi \to p) \to \neg \neg p)$
- $\phi_{n+1}:=((\phi_n \to \neg \neg p) \to p)$

Take a sufficiently large $n$ and add the axiom $\neg \phi_n$.

I honestly have no idea how to calculate how long it would take to prove a contradiction without allowing assumptions/Deduction Theorem, meta-theorems, or meta-axioms/lemmas. However, it’s clear that the number of symbols increases by only $10$ between each  $\phi_n$ and $\phi_{n+1}$.

Comment: This proposal is in *propositional* logic, which is a rather different setting from ZFC. In particular, ZFC has no propositional atoms (your "$p$"), so the sentences you describe are not in fact sentences in the language of ZFC.

Comment: How can a formal system that uses FOL not have propositional atoms? What are 0-ary predicates if not propositional atoms? I’ve never heard this before.

Comment: @PW_246 propositional atoms (or at least things resembling them) are *allowed* in first order languages. But the signature for the language of set theory is just one binary relation…

Comment: How could there be a first-order property for the axiom of separation without predicate symbols other than $\in$? Either way, the only way I’ve ever learned it is that FOL is built directly from PL, and set theory is an extension of FOL with $\in$ as the only *pre-defined* binary relation.

Comment: Also, if you have propositional and first-order tautologies with which to work, you have to have propositional atoms and predicate symbols as well.

Comment: Also, what of Diaconescu's  Theorem?

Comment: @PW_246 By building formulas with $\in$ as the only nonlogical symbol, like $\phi(x):=\forall y (x=y\land \lnot x\in x),$ for a random, mostly meaningless example. I don't understand your second contention at all... the existence of tautologies doesn't somehow change your language to have propositional atoms. You can certainly definitionally extend the language to add propositional atoms and define them as certain sentences, but they would not be "free", and e.g. you'd need to say what sentence $p$ is defined as.

Comment: @PW_246 Not sure exactly what you're getting at with Diaconescu's theorem. My knowledge of constructive set theory is very limited but I always viewed the 'toy version' as a proof that over a constructive ZF with full separation, AC implies the schema $\phi\lor \lnot \phi$ where $\phi$ ranges over all sentences in the language of set theory. I don't see how propositional variables would add anything here (but I could be wrong)... one could also think of LEM as a *second-order* statement $\forall P (P\lor \lnot P)$ but that's another thing entirely.

Comment: What I’m saying is that if you use propositional or first order logic, you get what comes with it. You also clearly cannot just define a propositional variable $p$ as a specific formula, otherwise you’d be doing second-order reasoning.

Comment: You need a propositional variable in the disjunctions that define the requisite sets to prove LEM from AC.

Comment: @PW_246 You are confusing the logic with specific language instances and your remark about second order reasoning makes no sense. You don't need a propositional variable (at least in how I'm interpreting it)... the 'proposition' in the proof is a metavariable ranging over sentences of the language, not a propositional variable in the language. (And if you think it's meaningful the other way, then *you*'d be doing second-order reasoning... or that's the only way I could make sense of it, anyway.)

Comment: A meta-variable is by definition higher-ordered than the object language. I also don’t see how showing that a 0-th order propositional variable obeys LEM doesn’t imply LEM for any proposition, in just the same way that proving it for a random propositional variable is sufficient to prove it for all propositions in PL.

Comment: @PW_246  On the latter point I think what you're saying makes sense, but don't see what it adds to just interpreting it as a schema over sentences in signature $\{\in\}.$

Comment: Not everything that can be mathematically expressed can be expressed in first-order ZF, but those propositions can just be interpreted as propositional variables. The predicate “$f$ is a fast-growing function” can be talked about as a pure proposition. Since it’s a propositional variable, we won’t be able to actually prove anything about it other than the usual tautologies.

Comment: If set theories are not just the result of adding axioms to logic, ok; but I don’t see what it *detracts* to maintain the usual FOL validities, including the propositional ones.

Comment: @PW_246 Doing things the standard way doesn't fail to maintain propositional validities... every instance of a propositional tautology is valid here. And all we are doing *is* adding non-logical axioms to a deductive system (one that already proves every instance of a tautology you can form in the language, plus any first-order validity). The issue here is syntax: there aren't any propositional variables in the language. That doesn't conflict in any way with the above.

Comment: Propositional validities are a subset of first order validities.

Comment: First order validities involve more than just one relation. A validity isn’t just an adherence to a specific form of reasoning; it’s a property that applies to specific formulas in a formal system, than can then be generalized outside of the system. I just don’t believe you that standard ZFC doesn’t have propositional variables in it just because ZFC already “takes place” in FOL, which still retains propositional variables. It’s like saying GIT can’t be formalized in PA because $Bew$ isn’t in the signature {$(, ), ,, =, x_i, s, \in, \forall, \to, \bot, ∅$}.